# Proof that the area of a rectangle is $\ell\times b$

Tags: geometry

Can anybody prove that the area of a rectangle is length * width

Comment: what is $l$ and what is $b$?

Comment: the perimeter may be?

Comment: Perimeter, not area!

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the area

Comment: Not unless you can define "area" in a way that doesn't already assume the area of a rectangle is base $\times$ height

Comment: I disagree with the proposal to close this question. And I've up-voted it.  Can those proposing to close it explain why they want to do that? $\qquad$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra : I would guess the letters $\ell$ and $b$ stand for "length" and "breadth".  I'm more accustomed to "length" and "width" or to "base" and "height". $\qquad$

Comment: @MPW : That's a good point, and a good answer to this question should address that.  (But if you meant that it's absurd to think there's a good way to define it other than as "base" times "height", then you should put your brain in gear and try again.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: No, I didn't mean that. But OP didn't furnish any other information or description of what he intends as a measure of area. You must admit that the question truly is unclear because of that.

Answer (score 4):

What is area in the first place? I shall assume that area is a function $\mu$ that maps *certain* subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ to non-negative real numbers subject to the following conditions:

- If $\mu(A)$ and $\mu(B)$ are defined, then $\mu(A\cup B)$ is defined and $\mu(A\cup B)\le \mu(A)+\mu(B)$. If additionally $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$
- If $\mu(A)$ and $\mu(B)$ are defined and $A\subseteq B$, then $\mu(B\setminus A)$ is defined.
- If $\mu(A)$ is defined and $B$ is congruent to $A$, then $\mu(B)$ is defined and $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$
- $\mu([0,1]\times[0,1])=1$
- If $A$ is a set such that $\sup\{\,\mu(B)\mid B\subseteq A, \mu(B)\text{ is defined}\,\}=\inf\{\,\mu(B)\mid B\supseteq A, \mu(B)\text{ is defined}\,\}$
  then $\mu(A)$ is defined

Using these rules, we conclude that $\mu([0,a[\times[0,1])=\mu(([0,1]\times[0,1])\setminus([a,1+a]\times[0,1]))$ is defined for all $a\in(0,1)$. Next, $$\tag1\mu([0,na[\times[0,1])=n\mu([0,a[\times[0,1]).$$
From this, $$\tag2\frac1{\lfloor \frac 1a\rfloor +1}\le \mu([0,a[\times[0,1])\le \frac1{\lfloor \frac 1a\rfloor }$$
for $0<a\le 1$. Using $(1)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\lfloor\frac1{a/n}\rfloor +1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\lfloor\frac1{a/n}\rfloor }=a$, we conclude$$\mu([0,a[\times [0,1])=a$$
first for $0<a\le 1$ and by using $(1)$ for all $a>0$.
Repeat this procedure in the other dimension to conclude 
$$ \mu([0,a[\times[0,b[)=ab$$
for all $a,b>0$. Finally note that it doesn't matter whether we think oif our rectangles as products of open or closed or half-open intervals.

Comment: @Hagen : May I suggest that you up-vote the question? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Area should be additive, i.e. the area of the union of two regions that don't overlap should be the sum of their areas.

As a first approximation, let's suppose the plane consists of discrete points in a rectangular grid:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet
\end{array}
$$
How much space the "rectangle" above takes up is a matter of how many dots there are.  There are four columns of three dots each or three rows of four dots each, hence $3\times 4$, which it length times width, or base times height if you prefer.

But then we remember that squares can be subdivided into smaller squares:
$$
\text{Each “} \bullet \text{'' is one of these: }\quad  \vdots \, \vdots \, \vdots
$$

And area should be additive, so that the area of a union of several rectangles should be the sum of their areas.
$$
\begin{array}{|cccc|ccc|}
\hline
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\hline
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The desiderata above logically ultimately lead to $\text{“area} = \text{length}\times\text{width''}$. (Nit-picking details have been omitted.)